# On an Exercise in finding the rank of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

The exercise states

> Given $A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> a & b & c \\
> 3 & 0 & 2 \\
> 1 & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ knowing that $\det(A) = 1$ find the rank of $N = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> a-1 & b-1 & c-1 & 0 \\
> 4 & 1 & 3 & a \\
> 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{array} \right) $

The fact that $\det(A) = 1$ tells us that $ +3c-2a-b = 1$ but I kind seem to figure out how to use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$Look at the subdeterminant: $$ \begin{align*}\begin{vmatrix} a-1 & b-1 & c-1 \\ 4 & 1  & 3 \\ 1 & 1  & 1\end{vmatrix} &= \begin{vmatrix} a & b & c \\ 3+1 & 0+1  & 2+1 \\ 1 & 1  & 1\end{vmatrix} - \cancelto{0}{\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 4 & 1  & 3 \\ 1 & 1  & 1\end{vmatrix}} \\ &= \begin{vmatrix} a & b & c \\ 3 & 0  & 2 \\ 1 & 1  & 1\end{vmatrix} + \cancelto{0}{\begin{vmatrix} a & b & c \\ 1 & 1  & 1 \\ 1 & 1  & 1\end{vmatrix}} \\ &= 1 \neq 0.\end{align*}$$Since we have a $3\times 3$ subdeterminant which is non-zero in a $3\times 4$ matrix, follows that ${\rm rank}(N) = 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix and $\det A\neq 0$ it follows that rank$(A)=3$, now, by performing elementary operations on the rows of $N$ we get
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
a-1 & b-1 & c-1 & 0 \\
4 & 1 & 3 & a \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c & 1 \\
3 & 0 & 2 & a-1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Where we have added row $3$ to the row $1$ and subtracted row $3$ from the row $2$ of $N$.

It follows rank$(N)=$ rank$(A)=3$.